# Manage query with dynamic data(commodity)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, entity-framework-5

I have a table in Database with dynamic records. I am getting the right result with static data (commodity), but I need result with dynamic data.

Database table Is :

```
Id  Month  Commodity  Amount
----------------------------
1   May     wheat      100
2   May     rice       200
3   June    wheat      400
4   July    maize      100
5   June    wheat      100
```

my result :

```
 Month      wheat    rice    maize
 --------------------------------
 May        100      200     
 June       500
 July                        100
```

My aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

and aspx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        getdata();
    }
}

public void getdata()
{
    using (GridFormatEntities context = new GridFormatEntities())
    {
        var result = (from r in context.tbl_Commodity
                          select new
                          {
                              Id = r.Id,
                              Month = r.Month,
                              Commodity = r.Commodity,
                              Amount = r.Amount
                          })
             .GroupBy(r => r.Month)
             .Select(r => new
             {
                 Month = r.Key,

                 Wheat = r.Where(x => x.Commodity == "Wheat").Sum(x => x.Amount),
                 Rice = r.Where(x => x.Commodity == "Rice").Sum(x => x.Amount),
                 maize= r.Where(x => x.Commodity == "maize").Sum(x => x.Amount),

             }).ToList();
        grdData.DataSource = result;
        grdData.DataBind();

    }
}
```

In above query it is coming static(wheat,rice and maize) but i need these commodities dynamically ... please help how can i manage the same with dynamic data (commodity).

Comment: First count no of Commodity ,with rows.count or count(sql), just write one loop for(i=0;i<r.commodity.count;i++) and replace commodity name with these static names

Comment: how could i use for loop in linq query ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a datatable instead of list, following code will help you. Please remember it is just a sample code to help you understand the concept. Please check for efficiency of loops according to your input data.

It fills the table, which you can assign to the datasource.

```
var list = new[]
                           {
                               new { Id = 1, Month = 2, Commodity = "Wheat", Amount = 20 },
                               new { Id = 2, Month = 2, Commodity = "Maize", Amount = 30 },
                               new { Id = 3, Month = 2, Commodity = "Barley", Amount = 30 },
                               new { Id = 4, Month = 1, Commodity = "Wheat", Amount = 20 },
                               new { Id = 5, Month = 1, Commodity = "Maize", Amount = 30 },
                               new { Id = 6, Month = 3, Commodity = "Barley", Amount = 30 }
                           };

            // group data by month and keep all rows
            var data =
                list.GroupBy(r => r.Month)
                    .Select(
                        r =>
                        new 
                            {
                                Month = r.Key,
                                Data = r.ToList()
                            })
                    .ToList();

            // get a list of all available commodities
            var allColumns = data.SelectMany(d => d.Data.Select(s => s.Commodity)).Distinct().ToList();

            // create a table
            var datatable = new DataTable();
            datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Month"));

            // add all commodities as columns
            allColumns.ForEach(c=>datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c)));

            // create 1 row for each month group and fill the columns
            data.ForEach(
                d =>
                    {
                        var row = datatable.NewRow();
                        row["Month"] = d.Month;
                        allColumns.ForEach(c => row[c] = d.Data.Where(g => g.Commodity == c).Sum(g => g.Amount));
                        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
                    });
```